Changing the properties of the all the objects of the environment?
i have created the environment using the openstreetmap in webots. now i have almost 400 roads and 100 building. I want to add boarder and bounding shape to all the roads , please tell me the quickest way to do this. can i do this using programming if yes how?
I tried reading the documentation but couldn't find anything related to this.
